# How can we mock using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Consider:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/attachment/answer/{answerId}"})
public APIResponse<List<AttachmentVM>> getAttachmentListForAnswer(@PathVariable("answerId") UUID answerId) {
    List<AttachmentBO> attachmentBOList = this.attachmentService.getAttachmentListForAnswer(answerId);
    List<AttachmentVM> noteVMList = super.mapList(attachmentBOList, AttachmentVM.class);
    return APIResponse.ok(noteVMList);
}
```

How can we write a JUnit testcase for this Controller using Mockito, using Mockito.when, and then return?

Comment: By using `.when` & `.thenReturn` - what have you tried? what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your API,  I would suggest [Wiremock](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock) instead of Mockito.

```java
@Test
public void shouldGetEndpoint() {
  String path = "/endpoint";
  wiremock.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(path))
          .willReturn(aResponse()
                  .withStatus(200))
  );
}
```

If you want to write a unit test for your class by mocking `attachmentService`, you will need to do something like:

```java
List<AttachmentBO> providedList = new ArrayList<>();
MyService attachmentService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
when(attachmentService.getAttachmentListForAnswer(any())).thenReturn(providedList);
```

Check out this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot).

```
@Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
@MockBean private AttachmentService attachmentService;

@Test public void test() {
     List<AttachmentBO> attachmentBOList = new ArrayList<>();
     String answerId = "myId";

     // mocking your service here by directly returning the list
     // instead of executing the code of the service class
     Mockito.when(attachmentService.getAttachmentListForAnswer(answerId))
            .thenReturn(attachmentBOList);

     // calling the controller
     String url = "/attachment/answer/" + answerId;
     this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url))
                 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status.isOk());
```

Comment: There is some information in comments, but I think an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? On what system and foundation was this tested on, incl. versions for all (incl. Java SDK and Spring Boot). From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70709114/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).